# duck type in fsharp and interoping with js

Tags: f#

I'm using fsharp's fable compiler to interact with js.

Suppose js passes an object to fsharp, but we don't know what type it is, only that it may have some properties.

In js, we can ignore the type of the object and access its properties directly,

for js code example:

```js
let msgheader = {
format: "standard",
sender: "tab",
receiver: "popup",
msg: {"content": "hello popup"}
id:2456
}

let {msg} = msgheader 
//msg: {"content": "hello popup"}
```

In fsharp, how can we access the properties directly when we don't know the type of the object?

In the case where the corresponding type cannot be defined, (for example, the format of the js object is not the same every time it is passed, sometimes it has "type" and "content", sometimes it may be a string) how should fsharp get the type or string of these js objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information about this in the Fable documentation page [Call JS from Fable](https://fable.io/docs/communicate/js-from-fable.html#call-javascript-from-fable). In particular, look at the [Dynamic typing](https://fable.io/docs/communicate/js-from-fable.html#dynamic-typing-dont-read-this) section.

The most primitive option is to use the dynamic access operator `?` which can be used as follows (copied from the docs):

```
open Fable.Core.JsInterop

printfn "Value: %O" jsObject?myProperty

let pname = "myProperty"
printfn "Value: %O" jsObject?(pname) // Access with a reference

jsObject?myProperty <- 5 // Assignment is also possible
```

For checking if you have a `string` value or something else, you could use the [Erased union](https://fable.io/docs/communicate/js-from-fable.html#other-special-attributes) approach, also documented on the Fable page.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I would also like to ask, if there is no help from fable, how to do it? 
If an object, don't know what type it is.
Is there any F# technique that can help me to access the properties and methods of this object safely?

Comment: @nevermind_15 If you are using F# with JS then the Fable APIs are the way to do it. For F# with .Net you have `FSharp.Interop.Dynamic` and `System.Reflection`.